# Existence of derivative

Tags: limits

Given a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. How to prove that the derivative of $f(x_0)$ exists iff there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such $f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + ah + R(h)$ where $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{R(h)}{h}} = 0$. I noted that if $f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + ah + R(h)$ then $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}} = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x_0) + ah + R(h) - f(x_0)}{h}} = a$ but I don't know how to end this prove. Any hints?

Comment: Well, that last limit is the definition of the derivative at $x_0$, so it looks like you're done with that implication. Now you need to show that if the derivative exists, the a function $R$ exists that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: But I haven't showed that if $f^{'}(x_0)$ exists then there exists such a.

Comment: How about putting $a=f'(x_0)$ and $R(h)=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-ah$ and seeing that this works?